Unable to cpp tests via ios_unit_test rule in bazel
I've been trying to add cpp tests via google test lib and run them via ios_unit_test target.. For some reason, the tests are not being executed at all.. I've tried to integrate the cpp tests lib directly or via objc_library and none of the approaches worked.. Here's the setup.
Module.bzl
module(
    name = "bazelsample",
    version = "0.0.1",
    repo_name = "bazel_sample"
)

bazel_dep(name = "apple_support", version = "1.15.1")
bazel_dep(name = "rules_apple", version = "3.5.1", repo_name="build_bazel_rules_apple")
bazel_dep(name = "rules_ios", version = "4.4.0", repo_name="build_bazel_rules_ios")
bazel_dep(name = "googletest", version = "1.14.0")

BUILD

load("@build_bazel_rules_apple//apple:ios.bzl", "ios_unit_test")
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

cc_library(
    name = "cpp_tests_lib",
    srcs = [
        "cpp_tests_lib/cpp_test.cpp",
    ],
    deps = [
        "@googletest//:gtest",
        "@googletest//:gtest_main",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

objc_library(
    name = "objc_tests_lib",
    srcs = [
        "objc_tests_lib/GoogleTests.mm",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":cpp_tests_lib",
        "@googletest//:gtest",
        "@googletest//:gtest_main",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    sdk_frameworks = ["XCTest"],
)

objc_library(
    name = "objc_cpp_tests_lib",
    srcs = [
        "cpp_tests_lib/cpp_test.cpp",
        "objc_tests_lib/GoogleTests.mm",
    ],
    deps = [
        "@googletest//:gtest",
        "@googletest//:gtest_main",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    sdk_frameworks = ["XCTest"],
)

ios_unit_test(
    name = "ios_cpp_tests_lib",
    minimum_os_version = "17.0",
    deps = [":cpp_tests_lib"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

ios_unit_test(
    name = "ios_objc_tests_lib",
    minimum_os_version = "17.0",
    deps = [":objc_tests_lib"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

ios_unit_test(
    name = "ios_objc_cpp_tests_lib",
    minimum_os_version = "17.0",
    deps = [":objc_cpp_tests_lib"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)


Here's the cpp test class
cpp_test.cpp

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(YourTestSuite, YourTestCase) {
    EXPECT_EQ(2 + 2, 4);
}

TEST(YourTestSuite, YourTestCaseTwo) {
    EXPECT_EQ(2 + 2, 4);
}

And I've used the GoogleTests.mm file to connect cpp google tests with XCTest during runtime. Here's the link to the file.
The cpp tests aren't getting loaded into google tests lib during runtime and I've also confirmed via static method that cpp tests classes code doesn't get executed at all during runtime unless invoked from objc test class.
Here's the sample project https://github.com/prasadpamidi/Bazel-iOS-Cpp-Sample
Am I missing something or is it not possible to integrate and run cpp tests via ios_unit_test rule?
Appreciate any help.

Adding alwayslink = True to cc_library rule fixed the issue
cc_library(
    name = "cpp_tests_lib",
    srcs = [
        "cpp_tests_lib/cpp_test.cpp",
    ],
    deps = [
        "@googletest//:gtest",
        "@googletest//:gtest_main",
    ],
    alwayslink = True,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)


